# Is it possible to synchronize an entire Windows 7 installation between multiple computers?

Tags: windows-7

I'm interested in knowing whether it's possible to synchronize an entire Windows 7 installations between two computers, so that any installed programs, files, and settings will be automatically synced between two different computers. Is there any way to do this in real time, so that the two installations would exactly mirror each other on two different machines?

Comment: It might be possible to synchronize a virtual machine between two computers. I wonder if there is any better solution than this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233982/syncing-contents-of-virtual-machines

Comment: make all the important folders symbolic links to a server?